# Videoview can't play videos selected through ES File Explorer

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, file-storage

Videoview not able to play videos selected through ES File Explorer(Getting "Can't play this video" in videoview).However it able to play videos when selected through device's default file manager or storage.

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO) {
                selectedVideoUri = data.getData();
                videoView.setVideoURI(selectedVideoUri);
                videoView.start();

               …
```

I debugged and found values for selectedVideoUri for same videos-

selectedVideoUri for Default File Manager or storage-

```
content://com.lenovo.FileBrowser.FileProvider/root_path/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp%20Video/VID-20200902-WA0001.mp4
```

selectedVideoUri for ES File Explorer-

```
content://com.estrongs.files/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp%20Video/VID-20200902-WA0001.mp4
```